# How do I allow HTTP/HTTPS for GCE instances that are created using a template?

Tags: http, networking, https, google-cloud-platform

I have created a Google Compute Engine Instance Template with the following firewall options set:

[image: GCE Instance Group Template]

I then create an Instance Group from that template, but I can't seem to reach the instance via HTTP/HTTPS. When I look at the settings for the Instance Group, I see that the HTTP/HTTPS boxes are *not* checked:

[image: GCE Instance Group Firewall setting]

What's going on here? Shouldn't these boxes be checked? Is there some other way I should allow HTTP/HTTPS for the instance group/instances created from a template?

Comment: Include your template with your question. Did you specify tags in your template?

Comment: I can't include the entire template due to privacy concerns; I can paste screenshots of specific parts, though, if needed. The Network Tags section is as shown above; I didn't add any custom tags. Which additional tags do I need to add?

Comment: Can  you show your firewall rules? And what is the problem? HTTP request doesn't come in to the server? Or the checkbox are simply not ticked?

Answer (score 5):

> I call this a "Plausible answer" which means that it fits my knowledge
>   base and experience but may be wrong ... please use with caution and
>   PLEASE comment if it is off base and we can remove.

Let us think about the creation of a Compute Engine through the wizard that is Cloud Console.  Obviously, it creates a Compute Engine. However, it also seems to perform *additional* tasks that are *not* **just** the creation of a Compute Engine.

If we imagine running gcloud commands to create the same thing as we see in the console, what might we find?  Actually, there is a solid answer for that.  If you visit the Cloud Console and enter your details (including checking the boxes), there is a link at the bottom which shows the equivalent gcloud command.

Surprise!! ... Creating a Compute Engine through the console doesn't just run a single gcloud command, it runs a few.  Specifically:

```
gcloud beta compute ... instances create instance-1 ...
gcloud compute ... firewall-rules create default-allow-http ...
gcloud compute ... firewall-rules create default-allow-https ...
```

and *there* is the answer.  The concept of clicking those checkboxes in the Cloud Console has *zero* relationship to the definition of a Compute Engine and adds *additional* but *serparate* commands to configure a VPC network firewall set of rules.

Thinking this forward, if we then look to create a template that is used when new instances of Compute Engines are created, these templates will *also* not contain any information related to creation of firewall rules.   I would expect the templates to create Compute Engine tags of `http-server` and `https-server`.  Please check that your template includes those.  If they do, then nothing left to say and we have a full explanation.